# Persistent AKS container's log

Tags: azure, containers, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics

I have an AKS cluster on Dev Env that has some containers running on it. I have also enabled the Azure Log Analytics on it. But I can see the logs of the current container that are running not the old ones which has been killed or stopped.

I'm wondering how I can keep the logs permanently even the container that has been deleted ot stopped. What is the best solution for it? I hoped that Azure logs can do it but it seems it doesn't.

Comment: it should, why do you think they are not there?

Comment: because when I search it using query, it only shows me the logs from last two days.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use Azure Monitor for Containers (can be enabled post-deployment of the cluster): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-overview

It collects logs from pods and stores them in a Log Analytics workspace, where they can be queried using the Kusto Query Language.

Comment: I am using Azure Monitor however it doesn't keep the logs for a long time. It just keeps them for a few days as I can see in my AKS azure portal. How long Azure monitor is suppose to keep the container logs? At the end I had to create a persistent volume and mount it to my pod in order not to loose the old logs and the logs of terminated pods. https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv

Comment: if I filter for the logs from last 30 dys, it doesn't show anything...

Comment: @Matrix did you get anywhere with this?